# How to get value from DOM window in Selenium webdriver(Java)

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am writing a script where I need to automate captcha code.
I have installed firebug in firefox. So when I right click on captcha code and go to inspect element I can see panels like HTML, CSS, DOM etc...
In DOM panel I can see the captcha code.
But I dont know how to access it.

Comment: Please elaborate your question.

Comment: You go to any website, rightclick on any element and click on inspect element. Now You will see HTML,CSS,DOM etc... If you go to DOM you will see Window and some properties. I want to read some value from DOM @VikasNehaOjha

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read the guide [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) then come back and edit your question so we can better help you.

Comment: @JeffC I have updated. I don't have ability to upload a print screen. I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Thanks anyway! I got my annswer.

```js
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
  System.out.println(js.executeScript("return window.captchaText;"));
```